# How to create socket in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I am looking for a way to create socket file in Linux. I want when I `cat` a file to see everything sent to certain port. Is it possible to use something like mksock to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with netcat?

Comment: The thing is that I am wondering can I for example create my own arp packet with some hex editor and to send it directly to my nic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side :

```
nc -l -p 6666
```

Client side :

```
nc 127.0.0.1 6666 < /etc/passwd
```

that will print the `/etc/passwd` file on server's output.

Does this fits your needs ?

**Edit** :

it seems like you need to forge packets, so I recommend you using [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

Comment: what about arp packet. How to send custom packets over the network.

Comment: This one looks great. thank you very match!

Answer (score 1):

You could do tcpdump and grep for the certain port you want to see everything send and received.